# Why were ducks blamed for Starbrow's Rebellion?

Tags: glorantha

I'm in the early stages of preparing an all-duck campaign set in Glorantha, at the time Fazzur Wideread issued the edict that made the Durulz Tribe the scapegoats of Starbrow's Rebellion, put a bounty on their heads, and initiated the pogrom that drove them into the zombie-infested Upland Marsh.

Unfortunately I know very little about the public and real reasons for the edict against the ducks, which will probably matter if my group's duck refugees run into Sartarites who have a complicated relationship with the occupying Lunars (i.e., most of them).

I know that Starbrow's Rebellion is covered by several different books—I could go get one of them if I knew which answered the question, but most are out of print and acquiring a half-dozen books to track down one sentence or paragraph isn't feasible. There's very little mention of ducks in *The Guide to Glorantha*.

Why were the ducks blamed for the war and made scapegoats?

Answer (score 5):

*I personally have never played in/read about a Glorantha setting, but this is what I found out from Google*

The use of the Durulz as a scapegoat in particular does not get much attention outside of the aftermath (i.e, Duck Hunt).

It appears that Fazzur Wideread considered the Ducks to be the ringleaders and major proponents of the rebellion.

> Fazzur marched to Boldhome and was received by Temertain. They were
>   very friendly, and soon sent most of their armies home. Fazzur agreed
>   to pardon all of the recent rebels except for one group, who he said
>   were the cause of the entire trouble. These were the Durulz or
>   wereducks, one of the beastpeople who had been loyal to Sartar.
>   Temertain agreed. Peace was made.

http://www.jane-williams.me.uk/glorantha/kallyr/sources.cfm

However, there are multiple mentions of the *Sartar High Council Scenario* within *Wyrm's Footprints* with claims that this is where to go for more detail on the events in question.

> One of their leaders, Jonathan Greenbeak [Joseph Greenface], was a (the?) foremost
>   advocate for a united rebellion at Sartar High Council (another
>   freeform I overlooked, published in Wyrm's Footprints

http://glorantha.temppeli.org/digest/gd6/1999.05/5069.html

and in this discussion with basically the same question
groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/HeroQuest-RPG/conversations/topics/29218